# Rails 5: devise invitable invited_by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

Recently I installed `devise_invitable` to my application, I'm currently trying to figure out how to display the of the inviter.

In my view I'm trying to get the fullname of the user who sent an invite.

I tried the following:

Example.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= user.fullname %> # Gives me the name of the user
 <%= user.invited_by %> # Gives me ActiveRecord Association
 <%= user.invited_by.fullname %> # Gives me an undefined method error
<% end %>
```

I would like to achieve this `<%= user.invited_by.fullname %>` is this possible?

#### Migration for devise_invitable

```
class DeviseInvitableAddToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.string     :invitation_token
      t.datetime   :invitation_created_at
      t.datetime   :invitation_sent_at
      t.datetime   :invitation_accepted_at
      t.integer    :invitation_limit
      t.references :invited_by, polymorphic: true
      t.integer    :invitations_count, default: 0
      t.index      :invitations_count
      t.index      :invitation_token, unique: true # for invitable
      t.index      :invited_by_id
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.remove_references :invited_by, polymorphic: true
      t.remove :invitations_count, :invitation_limit, :invitation_sent_at, :invitation_accepted_at, :invitation_token, :invitation_created_at
    end
  end
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service

  has_many :services
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :articles
  has_many :lists
end
```

Comment: Can you post the migration with which you added the `devise_invitable` related fields, please? Also the `User` model where you put the `invited_by` association will help.

Comment: Added the `User` model and the `migration`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that not all of your users are invited by someone, so you need to check if `invited_by` is present first:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.fullname %>
  <% if user.invited_by.present? %>
    <%= user.invited_by %>
    <%= user.invited_by.fullname %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also when you send the invitation be sure that you are passing which user is sending the invite, since this parameter is optional:

```
User.invite!({:email => "new_user@example.com"}, current_user) # current_user will be set as invited_by
```

Comment: I checked the `InvitationsController` and there was a typo! Thank you, I've solved the problem.